# Can't drill deep enough into the wall nor the ceiling; what am I doing wrong?

Tags: drill

I need some guidance in this DIY wizardry. I've always had trouble drilling the ceiling in my house, but now I'm having the same trouble with a wall. I've relegated myself to avoid drilling at all costs but I want to know what am I doing wrong.

I've already used the hammer action of my drill, but with the same result.

I can drill very easily for a few millimeters, and then I can't get past that. Here are some photos of my latest failures along with the drill and the bit I'm using. The tools are very old, they belonged to my father, so I wonder if that's the problem.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the construction of your house? Plaster over wood studs? Poured concrete?

Comment: Does it feel like the drill has any percussive action when you're drilling? It wouldn't be too dramatic... much like a strong buzzing. (I'm wondering if your drill isn't getting into hammer mode properly.)

Comment: OK admit it . . . your 'house' is the jail house. You are trying to get us to participate in a jailbreak! Or is this some unusual architect design concrete house? Where is it?

Comment: I hate to suggest this, but are you sure the drill is turning the right direction?  It should be rotating clockwise as you're holding it against the wall.

Comment: You might need a machine with more hammering energy.

Comment: The second picture looks like it might be brick. Clockwise (normally labelled with a forwards arrow, F or R for right) and hammer action should work fine. It might be a bit slow, and will be much slower than  through any plaster on top.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I'm not sure about it, how can I tell?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Yes, I can definitely feel a big difference in vibration and noise.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I just double checked and it's turning clockwise.

Comment: You can tell if it is brick by feeling it or scratching at it with your fingernail:  does it feel like brick or rock or ceramics?  Does it feel like wood, plastic, metal, etc.?  Maybe use a sharp pocketknife or carpentry nail to poke at it.

Comment: @JimStewart I plead the 5th about the first question... as for the location, it's in Portugal. it's an 8th-story residential building in a city.

Comment: @Smig So, that's almost certainly a concrete structure, and you may be going through plaster into concrete.

Comment: If that's an old drill bit, it could be quite dull. Couple that with the fact that you have a pretty basic drill and a large size drill bit (I'm guessing 3/8"/8mm at least) and your troubles are understandable. Can you rent/borrow a rotary hammer (like a Bosch Bulldog)?

Comment: Any chance you're hitting reinforcing rod?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your not using a masonry drill bit?  It will drill through the drywall, but you will have a tough time if you hit wood behind it.

Comment: Apparently I am using masonry bits. I'll try with general purpose ones next.

Comment: It's hard to see, but I don't think there's wood back there. A general purpose drill bit would just grind itself dull on stone.

Answer (score 2):

Your photos show a masonry drill bit.  General purpose drill bits look like [these](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DEWALT-Titanium-Pilot-Point-Drill-Bit-Set-21-Piece-DW1361/202279642).
[image]

I cannot tell what material the wall is made of from your photos.  One looks likely to be sheetrock (gypsum board), but the other is uncertain.

A masonry bit eventually will grind through sheetrock, but is highly ineffective on wood—probably igniting it with enough persistence.  (However, the masonry bit will do great in concrete.)

Comment: I'm going to get some general purpose bits this week and see if it makes a difference.